# IndexError: list index out of range / couldnt append a number to the array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im working on a project and I need to append a number to the control array but its not appending.

```py
CezaSayac = 0
i = 0
control = []
control.clear()
for i in range(3):
    if(resultsList[i][index][1] == self.GercekSayilar[self.x]):
        control[i].append = self.GercekSayilar[self.x]
    else:
        control[i].append = self.GercekSayilarTersi[self.x]
        CezaSayac += 1
for a in len(control):
    if(control[a] == 1):
        self.katsayilar[a] += 1 / (ArrayUzunlugu)
    else:
        self.katsayilar[a] -= ((CezaSayac)/ArrayUzunlugu)/(ArrayUzunlugu-CezaSayac)
```

And `kontrol[i].append = self.GercekSayilar[self.x]` in the above code returns the below error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Incorrect usage of `append`. Instead of `control[i].append = ` you should use `control.append(value)`

Comment: that mean index `i` doesn't exist in `kontrol`, check it's size and verify

Comment: but its giving array if i do control[i].append =

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `control[i].append = self.GercekSayilar[self.x]` , you should use `control.append(self.GercekSayilar[self.x])`